# about flutter TabBar

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

Are there similar components in flutter? Or can any profession guy provide me with the code? Thank you.

I can't find package like this Effect，My request is to show all the tabs after the Animatedcontainer opens the tabbar.

Comment: Hello Welcome to Stack overflow and thanks for showing your efforts. You also need to add your efforts as what code you tried and what didn't work for you. Where you got stuck, etc. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want `ExpansionTile` and I made it as simple and quick.

```dart
class ExpansionGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  const ExpansionGrid({
    super.key,
    required this.itemList,
  });

  final List<YourItem> itemList;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ExpansionTile(
      tilePadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      childrenPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 40),
      // it's kind dirty. You may use Row() for title instead.
      title: GridView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          mainAxisSpacing: 10,
          crossAxisSpacing: 10,
        ),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => itemList.sublist(0, 3)[index],
        itemCount: itemList.sublist(0, 3).length,
      ),
      children: [
        GridView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 3,
            mainAxisSpacing: 10,
            crossAxisSpacing: 10,
          ),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => itemList.sublist(3)[index],
          itemCount: itemList.sublist(3).length,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
class YourItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const YourItem({
    super.key,
    required this.name,
  });

  final String name;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.grey,
      child: Center(child: Text(name)),
    );
  }
}
```

You will need to custom it to make better and more fits to your image.

I hope it helped.